# jQuery/CSS: fixed overlay should not allow scrolling of background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

i have a overlay box that is fixed and centered on the screen. The page itself is rather long and has a vertical scrollbar.

I'd like to disable scrolling of the page itself once the overlay is shown. However I can't disable scroll completely because some overlays do have `overflow-y:scroll` for themselves. So the content in the overlay should be scrolled but the page itself should be stuck.

Any idea how to solve that with jquery or css?

Comment: I think you meant 'overflow-y: scroll' and not 'overflox-y' ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest and dirtiest way I can think of is to attach an event listener to the window for scroll events, and preventDefault() if your overlay is visible.

like so (using jquery).

```
   window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var el = $('.overlay.active');

        if( el.length > 0 ){
            e.preventDefault();
        }   
   });
```

Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` doesn't work for window scroll for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `body` to `overflow: hidden`. This will prevent scrolling. Child's overflow declarations stay unaffected. I have done a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FC53Y/).

Comment: the problem is that the page will jump once the scrollbars are hidden

Comment: i thought about any solution that just prevents the onScroll handler from scrolling

Comment: This worked perfectly from me in keeping the overlay scrollable but the body won't scroll any more.. great!

Comment: This used to work but it's no longer supported in Mobile Safari. Sad face!

Comment: plus one if you always appreciate someone including the fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Just an adjustment to Marc's jQuery solution. My code disables the body scroll as the overlay appears, then when the body or overlay close button is clicked, the body scroll is re-enabled.

```
/*We disable the scroll*/

$(function() {
/*This is where we specify what button is being clicked to open the 
overlay, change at will.*/
$('#overlay1').click(function() {    
/*This is where we specify what part of the page is gonna disable the 
scroll, in this case the body.*/
    $('body')   
        .css('overflow', 'hidden');
   });

/*Now we re-enable the scroll*/

/*This is where we specify the the part of the overlay that is being 
clicked to close it, in this case, the body and the .close, change at will.*/
$('body, .close').click(function() {
/*This is where we specify the part of the page we are re-enabling 
the scroll, in this case the body.*/
    $('body')
        .css('overflow', 'visible');
   });
});
```

Here's a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MasEE/) of my script in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can position your overlay as a `{position: fixed;}`. That will [keep your overlay in your screen](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) even if your page scrolls.

Comment: yeah, that is already the case! :) I wonder how i can prevent the rest of the page from scroling. The overlay is kept in place, but i can still use my scrollwheel and scroll the content behind the fixed overlay.

Comment: well, in that case you can use nasty hacks. Did you try changing body's `overflow` to `hidden`?

Comment: the problem is that then the page jumps a few pixels since the scrollbar disappears. any other ideas? maybe with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an full width and full height container, with `position: fixed`. And inside this container create your actual overlay with info. The container basically blinds the user from scrolling or interacting with the page.